# Interrupt handler: request_irq returns error code -16

Tags: c, linux-kernel, driver, interrupt-handling, irq

I am writing a simple driver, which could register an interrupt and handle it.
I am using the `request_irq` function but it returns this error:

```
genirq: Flags mismatch irq 29. 00004004 (irq-test) vs. 00000004 (e000d000.spi)
- code -16 , EIO 5 , EINVAL 22
```

This is the simple module code:

```
#define IRQ_Number 29

static irqreturn_t irq_handler( int irq, void *dev_id )
{
    static int mycount = 0;


printk("Interrupt! = %d\n", mycount);
    mycount++;

return IRQ_HANDLED;

}
static int __init my_init(void)
{
unsigned int irq;

int ret;

irq = IRQ_Number;   

ret = request_irq(irq, irq_handler , IRQF_NO_SUSPEND; , "irq-test", NULL);

if(ret != 0) {
        printk("ERROR: IRQ request failed %d", irq);
        printk(" - code %d , EIO %d , EINVAL %d\n", ret, EIO, EINVAL);
  }
    return 0;

}
static void __exit my_exit(void)
{

    unsigned int irq;
    irq=IRQ_Number;
    free_irq(irq, NULL);

    printk(KERN_INFO "my module: ----> exit\n" );

}
```

And this the output from `cat /proc/interrupts`:

```
           CPU0       CPU1       
 16:          1          0     GIC-0  27 Edge      gt
 17:          0          0     GIC-0  43 Level     ttc_clockevent
 18:  140949401 1430637760     GIC-0  29 Edge      twd
 19:          0          0     GIC-0  37 Level     arm-pmu
 20:          0          0     GIC-0  38 Level     arm-pmu
 21:         43          0     GIC-0  39 Level     f8007100.adc
 23:          7          0     GIC-0  57 Level     cdns-i2c
 25:          0          0     GIC-0  35 Level     f800c000.ocmc
 26:        332          0     GIC-0  59 Level     xuartps
 27:   14833917          0     GIC-0  58 Level     e0006000.spi
 28:          2          0     GIC-0  81 Level     e0007000.spi
 29:          0          0     GIC-0  51 Level     e000d000.spi
 30:    3654689          0     GIC-0  54 Level     eth0
 31:        637          0     GIC-0  56 Level     mmc0
 32:          0          0     GIC-0  45 Level     f8003000.dmac
 33:          0          0     GIC-0  46 Level     f8003000.dmac
 34:          0          0     GIC-0  47 Level     f8003000.dmac
 35:          0          0     GIC-0  48 Level     f8003000.dmac
 36:          0          0     GIC-0  49 Level     f8003000.dmac
 37:          0          0     GIC-0  72 Level     f8003000.dmac
 38:          0          0     GIC-0  73 Level     f8003000.dmac
 39:          0          0     GIC-0  74 Level     f8003000.dmac
 40:          0          0     GIC-0  75 Level     f8003000.dmac
 41:          0          0     GIC-0  40 Level     f8007000.devcfg
 48:          0          0     GIC-0  41 Edge      f8005000.watchdog
IPI1:          0          0  Timer broadcast interrupts
IPI2:     371883   12507844  Rescheduling interrupts
IPI3:          4          1  Function call interrupts
IPI4:          0          0  CPU stop interrupts
IPI5:    2632663   10068764  IRQ work interrupts
IPI6:          0          0  completion interrupts
```

I tried changing flags to 0 and `IRQF_SHARED`, but got the same error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A return value of `-16` means error 16, which is `EBUSY` a.k.a. "device or resource busy". You are trying to request IRQ 29, and you can clearly see that IRQ 29 is already registered by `e000d000.spi`. This means that whoever wrote the code for that driver decided not to use `IRQF_SHARED`, and therefore you cannot request it, even if you specify that flag. Use another number to request a different interrupt line, or avoid loading the driver that takes exclusive control of that line.

Also, I'm not sure why you are also printing the two values of `EIO` and `EINVAL`, but those are just error numbers without any context, not something that is being returned by the function.